# TFS 2018 : TF30042: The Database is Full

Tags: tfs-2018

Got this Error...

```
TF30042: The Database is Full. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.
Error:1101, Message: could not allocate a new page for database 'Tfs_DefaultCollection' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'PRIMARY'. Create the necessary space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
```

How to increase size of TFS 2018 database ? Don't have UI to check size and all on server how to change database config through command line?

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool that ships with TFS to alter the files. But any SQL Server management tool will work. I generally use SQL Server management studio to either change the database files directly or to generate the script to change the file size.

[Using `sqlcmd` you can open an interactive session to the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511) that your TFS server stores all its data in. [You can then issue an `ALTER DATABASE` statement to change the max size of the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-ver16&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511).

```
ALTER DATABASE tfs_defaultcollection
MODIFY FILE  
(
  NAME = PRIMARY,  
  SIZE = 50MB
);
```

Set the new size in the statement above to be big enough. Alternatively, enable auto-growth by setting `SIZE = UNLIMITED`.